# How to animate AnimatedIcon with Hero?

Tags: flutter

I want to use Hero to animate the AnimatedIcon in the process of route navigation. What should I do?

```
_controller = AnimationController(
    duration: Duration(microseconds: 1000), value: 1.0, vsync: this);

void _toggleFrontLayer() {
  final AnimationStatus status = _controller.status;
  final bool isOpen = status == AnimationStatus.completed ||
      status == AnimationStatus.forward;
  _controller.fling(velocity: isOpen ? -2.0 : 2.0);
}

leading: Hero(
  child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
            progress: _controller,
          ),
          onPressed: _toggleFrontLayer,
        ),
      ),
  tag: "leading",
),

leading: Hero(
  child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
            progress: _controller,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
  tag: "leading",
),
```

The appbar looks like this:[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpK7P.gif)

And the AnimatedIcon's animation looks like this:[AnimatedIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YJOL.gif)

What I want is showing the animation of the AnimatedIcon in the process of route navigation instead of fade in and fade out or other animations.

Answer (score -1):

First things first. If you don't have a `Material` ancestor widget, you're probably getting an exception while you're routing between screens. To prevent it, you can wrap your `IconButton` in a `Material` with the property `color: Colors.transparent`.

Second, there is nothing wrong with using `Hero` to animate the leading button between screens, however, you won't notice a difference since the position is exactly the same and there is nothing to animate *from-to*. The result is something like this:

[image]

However, if you actually change the position of the `IconButton` between screens, you will get the `Hero` animation as expected.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry that I didn't describe the problem clearly and I update it just now. But the first thing you said actually help me solve the 'no material widget found' problem. My English is not very good and sorry again for my inaccurate description. Anyway, thanks a lot for you answer.